# Is it possible to have two "<input type=file>" within a single form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebug

Is it possible to have something like the following

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="upload.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Upload File 1</p>
<input type="file" name="file1"/>
<p>Upload File 2</p>
<input type="file" name="file2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I know I can use the [Jquery Multi-File-Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) plugin to upload multiple files from a single input element.
The situation is that the end user will be uploading multiple images of a product and I would like to be able to prompt them for sep. image for example one could be a front view and the second could be a back view. 
When I try the above HTML however I only see the first file being posted in Firebug.

**Update:**

Looks like this may be something with Firebug as when I modify the dest .ashx page to just spit back the filenames that it received from the post request I get both Files.
Also in the Firebug console I see this message buried amongst the posted data 
... Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That works fine for me.  The files are being uploaded to my server just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The inputs have the same name. Change the names or in PHP for example you can use the shortcut `name=file[]` and have an array

Comment: Sorry about that. In the real code the names are diff (I edited)  and it still only posts the first file.