# multiple input type file element jquery ajax php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I wan to put 2 input type file in my project meaning i want to be able to upload twice in one insert query. I am searching for sample but i have yet to find any. the only related article i found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107276/is-it-possible-to-have-two-input-type-file-within-a-single-form)  but is does not say much. When i say multiple input file i mean like this.

`<input type="file" name="file1"/>` - `first input file`

`<input type="file" name="file2"/>` - `second input file`

What i want to happened is select images in one input file and then again select other files(pdf for example) in another input file and be able to insert these files in separate table. I am using ajax in passing the information from html to my server side. I use pdo(php) and my database is mySQL.
Any idea is appreciated. Having an example would help best. Especially on how to determine which `$_file` is `from which input file`. If I can determine this I think i can be able to insert it to the specific table in server side

`UPDATE`

How to insert files from 2 input type file element(both can have multiple files)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [file1] => Array
        (
            [name] => MyFile.txt (comes from the browser, so treat as tainted)
            [type] => text/plain  (not sure where it gets this from - assume the browser, so treat as tainted)
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php1h4j1o (could be anywhere on your system, depending on your config settings, but the user has no control, so this isn't tainted)
            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK  (= 0)
            [size] => 123   (the size in bytes)
        )

    [file2] => Array
        (
            [name] => MyFile.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
            [size] => 98174
        )
)
```

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) I hope this will solve my problem